# Validate XML structure and content

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I have a small XML file that contains some configuration details.

Whilst it's only maintained once in a while, I can't help but think that it needs to be validated.

I've searched the web extensively, but haven't quite found what I'm looking for as yet. I'm also consious that there is much legacy XML functionality out there for C#/Asp.Net so I'm also trying to find something that is appropriate for 2015, not 2005.

Obviously, I'm looking to validate the structure but I also need to validate data - much like a guard clause would do - however, I'm not sure if this is the right approach in this instance.

I create a class from my XML like this:

```
        var agents = XmlHelper
            .Deserialise<AgentConfigs>("~/AgentConfig.xml")
            .Agents
            .Where(x => x.IsActive == true);
```

As you can see it's a helper class but it's nothing special behind the facade.

I could create a guard clause like this:

```
        Guard.Argument.IsValid(Agents.IsNotNullOrEmpty() &&
            !Agents.Any(x => (x.AmountStep.IsDefault())) &&
            !Agents.Any(x => (x.MaxAmount.IsDefault())) &&
            !Agents.Any(x => (x.MaxTerm.IsDefault())) &&
            !Agents.Any(x => (x.MinAmount.IsDefault())) &&
            !Agents.Any(x => (x.MinTerm.IsDefault())) &&
            !Agents.Any(x => (x.Name.IsNullOrEmpty())) &&
            !Agents.Any(x => (x.TermStep.IsDefault())) &&
            !Agents.Any(x => (x.Timeout.IsDefault())));
```

Again a helper class. But is doesn't feel right - maybe it is a practical approach but I'm not entirely sure.

Any thoughts?

Comment: That is why there is an xsd schema file.  You need to create a schema.

Comment: I'm a little perplexed. As I'm using the serializer, I will know whether the serialization has worked on creation - I'll also know the data is correct. The problem is I won't know until runtime. The XSD will resolve this, but I need to make copies of my XML file, so that it can be configured from project to project - so the XSD needs to be portable or centralised. It's this bit I have no knowlege of.

Comment: Then why do you need to verify the structure?  Normally you just need to verify xml when you develop the application not everytime you write the file.  XSD is normally used to determine the range of values are correct.  Like a number between 1 and 10.  An XSD file is normally in a central location on network (or url) and not under a single project.

Comment: This is the first time I've done anything like this, so what you're telling me is good.